# How to load data every seconds automatically in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I would like to load data automatically every seconds.

I use **setinterval** but it always said error like this

**"TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...this.state.forumContentData.map...')"**

Here is what I tried:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    forumContentData: []
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  // Set timer before going to the Next Action - Every Seconds
  this._interval = setInterval(() => {
    this.getForumContent();
  }, 1000);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this._interval);
}

getForumContent() {
  return fetch('http://' + ipAddress() + ':' + portAddress() + '/api/forum/view_thread', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    this.setState({forumContentData: responseJson}); // Get the data from API
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    //console.error(error);

    alert(error);
  });
}

render() {

  let forumContentResult = this.state.forumContentData.map((forumContentDataDetail, index) => {
      var forum_title = forumContentDataDetail.title;

      return (
        <Text>{forum_title}</Text>
      );
  });


}
```

What would be the best way to load data every seconds automatically in react native?

Comment: iam guessing your problem here. react renders once and tries to get `{form_title}` but its not there, because you need to await the return of your AJAX. try wrapping the render-return in something like `if (AJAX.success){return(//your code):}else{return(<div>Loading...</div>)}`

Comment: The error is still shown up even though I already added the condition. The problem is the request that I set in interval can not be stop. Actually I already added clear interval `clearInterval(this._interval);` but it still keeps loading the data.

Answer (score 0):

Inside setInterval the context is diferent. You are binding the setInterval but not the response from the promise.

Try this:

```
getForumContent() {
let self = this;
  return fetch('http://' + ipAddress() + ':' + portAddress() + '/api/forum/view_thread', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    self.setState({forumContentData: responseJson}); // Get the data from API
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    //console.error(error);

    alert(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: The error is still shown up. It still keeps loading the data even though I have moved to another component. Actually I already clear the interval, but it still keeps loading the data. `clearInterval(this._interval);`

Comment: I don't think is the interval. What is the responseJson value? Also, you are handling the map function wrong. If you have multiple items in the response, you are actually making multiple returns.